# debugging of spark job - map stage id to stage in SQL view

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I map the stage id / job id present in sparks (jobs) UI to the SQL visualization of stages?

I.e.

```
val df = Seq(("a",1,1, 10),("a",1,2, 20),("a",2,3, 30),("b",1,4, 40),("b",1,5, 50)).toDF("group", "id", "value1", "value2")
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val commonPartition = Window.partitionBy("group")

val enrich = Seq(("a", "x", "y"), ("b", "foo", "y")).toDF("group", "e1", "e2")
val enriched = df.join(enrich, Seq("group"), "INNER")

val ranked = enriched.withColumn("rank1", rank over commonPartition.orderBy(desc("value1"))).withColumn("rank2", rank over commonPartition.orderBy(desc("value2")))


//ranked.cache


val df1Top = ranked.filter(col("rank1") === 1).select(col("group"), col("id"), lit("foo").alias("rank1Top"))
val df2Top = ranked.filter(col("rank2") === 1).select(col("group"), col("id"), lit("bar").alias("rank2Top"))

val df1 = ranked.join(df1Top, Seq("group", "id")).drop("rank2")
val df2 = ranked.join(df2Top, Seq("group", "id")).drop("rank1")


df1.join(df2, Seq("id"), "FULL").show
```

[image]

stages:
[image]

where can I find `stage 25` in the SQL visualization graph?

## edit

[image]

Comment: You could see it in the Stages tab under DAG visualisation link.

Comment: See the edit. Indeed, one can see something there, but it still is note really meaningful.

Comment: this and the sql tab should give some further inputs to debug, Its little challenging and trickier

Comment: But this is what I am saying. It is rather challenging and I would prefer a simpler method.